# iOS - Server database

Tags: mysql, ios, sql-server, xcode, sqlite

I'm starting a new iOS project and don't really know how to procede. My app will be a personal agenda for doctors, it will contain tables of information with patience, and maybe some prescription.  I see it as being a farrelly complex app with a large data base.

If i would keep the information input from the doctors only in the local memory of the app i know i should use a SQL-lite data base. But i am considering syncronising the information stored for multiple devices, so the data must be sent to a server.

Here comes my question: Should i save the information written by the doctors into a database inside the app and send it to the server ? And ask for it back if changes were made. Or should i export the information into a JSON and send it so the server can save it into the database ?

Or maybe it's another way i could do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not send the database back and forth with server and client as this is very wrong practice

1)`Sqlite` database has more size than any `json` so it consumes more bandwidth.Sending back and forth is not appropriate.

2)`Json` is very lightweight so your client and server will have lesser overhead to communicate.

3)By taking `Sqlite` you are making server dependent on client as both have to work with same schema and your server need to work with sqlite in some cases it may not appropriate.

4)In future extending services with `json` is very easy and server can have their own design.

5)If your client needs part of information than server have to send whole database and fetch only relevant information from that database.

**Solution:**

1)You should make apis and client access these api's and consume `json` and do appropriate actions.
2)You can Consider `core data` and `iCloud` if you want to send data between iOS devices.It's bit clumsy to work with `icloud` and `core data` but you can consider it if it will fit with your needs